# Why does my negative lookbehind not work in Java?

Tags: java, regex

I am attempting to use negative lookbehind to do some matching on strings that will get sent into the system from another system that ours talks to. I have searched for similar questions and I have not been able to solve this based on any previously posted questions.

This works as expected

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile ("^(?<!SyCs-)([A-Za-z\\s\\d]+)$");
String s = "SyCs-a";

Assert.assertEquals (false, pattern.matcher (s).matches ());
```

Here's the problem: with the current regex, the following also returns false which makes sense because the '-' (dash) is not part of the allowed values **([A-Za-z\s\d]+)**.

```
s = "TyCs-a";

Assert.assertEquals (false, pattern.matcher (s).matches ());
```

However, I need that to return true but when I add the dash to allowed values, the first String returns true as well.

No dash

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile ("^(?<!SyCs-)([A-Za-z\\s\\d]+)$");
String s = "SyCs-a";

Assert.assertEquals (false, pattern.matcher (s).matches ());

s = "TyCs-a";

Assert.assertEquals (false, pattern.matcher (s).matches ());
```

With dash

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile ("^(?<!SyCs-)([A-Za-z\\s\\d-]+)$");
String s = "SyCs-a";

Assert.assertEquals (true, pattern.matcher (s).matches ());

s = "TyCs-a";

Assert.assertEquals (true, pattern.matcher (s).matches ());
```

I've tried to make the + not greedy +? but that doesn't change the outcomes at all.

Any suggestions?

Here's the whole set of tests that I am using to verify the regex

```
@Test
public void testNegativeLookBehind () {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile ("^(?<!SyCs-)([A-Za-z\\s\\d]+)$");
    String s = "SyCs-a";

    Assert.assertEquals (false, pattern.matcher (s).matches ());

    s = "SyCs-b";

    Assert.assertEquals (false, pattern.matcher (s).matches ());

    s = "SyCs-ab";

    Assert.assertEquals (false, pattern.matcher (s).matches ());

    s = "SyCs-ab1";

    Assert.assertEquals (false, pattern.matcher (s).matches ());

    s = "SyCs-abZ";

    Assert.assertEquals (false, pattern.matcher (s).matches ());

    s = "SyCs- abZ";

    Assert.assertEquals (false, pattern.matcher (s).matches ());

    s = "SyCs ab1";

    Assert.assertEquals (true, pattern.matcher (s).matches ());

    /*s = "TyCs-a";

    Assert.assertEquals (true, pattern.matcher (s).matches ());

    s = "SyCr-a";

    Assert.assertEquals (true, pattern.matcher (s).matches ());
    */
    s = "ab";

    Assert.assertEquals (true, pattern.matcher (s).matches ());

    s = "sab";

    Assert.assertEquals (true, pattern.matcher (s).matches ());

    s = "Csab";

    Assert.assertEquals (true, pattern.matcher (s).matches ());

    s = "yCsab";

    Assert.assertEquals (true, pattern.matcher (s).matches ());

    s = "SyCsab";

    Assert.assertEquals (true, pattern.matcher (s).matches ());
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The  `(?<!SyCs-)` is a negative lookbehind that fails the match if there is `CyCs-` immediately to the left of the current location. Since the current location is the start of string (`^`) the lookbehind *always* returns *true* and is just useless.

You need to use a lookahead here, not a lookbehind:

```
String pat = "^(?!SyCs-)[A-Za-z\\s\\d-]+$";
               ^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MPqGcZ/2).

The `^(?!SyCs-)` will check if the string starts with `SyCs-` and if it does, the  match will be failed.

Note that if you use the pattern with `.matches()` method, you may omit `^` and `$` anchors in the pattern as that method requires a full string match.